# How to use Empty Activity and still program in Java?

Tags: android-studio

I really am hating on Android Studio for this problem but I wish someone from StackOverflow would fix it. I really wanted to use the "Empty Activity" but as we all know after the recent Android Studio update we are no longer able to switch languages in "Empty Activity". The reason I need Empty Activity is because of the toolbar that it gives.

Is there a way to do this ?

I tried using the "Empty Views Activity" and adding the toolbar but didn't got the desired results. Sometimes the constraints weren't right and there were many more problems.